# How many memory addresses are there in 32k byte RAM?

Tags: memory-address, cpu-architecture

I'm aware that `32k = 32 * 2^10` which equals `**32768 memory addresses**`. However it is the byte that is throwing me off here. Does that indicate the width of the addressable memory?
How does the byte come into play here? Does that indicate byte addressable? If it were word addressable does that slash the available memory locations by half? Thanks for any replies in advance

Comment: Well to be pedantic, 32K actually = 32,000. 32KB = 32 Kilobytes and 32Kb=32kilobits. And this might help illuminate your question a little. 32K on it's own doesn't have anything to do with memory but 32KB and 32Kb start giving the question more context.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two things in the computer architecture:
1:Address bus(n-bit processor)
2:Memory,

here, address bus defines the number of addresses in your system, suppose if you have 16 bit processor, that means you may have 2^16 address space,
and if you have 32K byte RAM, then this represents the memory of your system.

Now, how these 32K memory is represented in 2^16 address space that is different and how the memory is accessed is based on the type of addressing, whether it is byte addressable or word addressable.